# How can an interactive function detect that it is invoked via an hydra?

Tags: key-bindings, hydra

Assume there's an interactive function `foo`.  Assume it is bound in various keymaps and is also bound inside an hydra as a simple key, let's say "a".

How can `foo`'s code detect that it was invoked via the hydra as opposed to any other way?  I'd like `foo` to be able to distinguish whether it was invoked when the hydra remapping the "a" key is active or otherwise (ie, if there are other non-hydra key bindings to it).

Also assume I have full control of the definition of that hydra (ie, the `defhydra` code that defines that specific hydra).

- The reason I want to know is that I want an interactive function to be available inside and outside an hydra.  When invoked inside the hydra I want the function to behave differently (in one case I want the function to first close the hydra and then execute the code, but I have other cases).

Answer (score 1):

I assume your last paragraph `(The reason...)`describe best your goals, IMHO.

To achieve that, you need to provide an optional argument to your function `foo`
and call that function without the argument outside hydra, and with the argument
inside hydra. The optional argument will be the flag to separate the operating
modes/tasks of that function.

Some examples how to do that are provided in your hydra installation folder,
see the file `hydra-examples.el`, in particular the example #12, where
the interactive function `org-agenda-log-mode` is called in three ways.

Comment: That's correct.  It answers my question as written.  I should have identified that I wanted to be able, for the function, to *not* be the function directly invoked by the hydra.  I really wanted to be able to determine dynamically if the hydra key map was active or not.  My question was not clear enough.